# how to set order asc or desc for datatable using code behind in C#?

Tags: asp.net, sorting, datatable

I have Temp table and i want to sort the data like order by itemid. Please help me how can we do this. Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
tableName.AsDataView().Sort = "itemId";
```